# Help understand difference in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select user_name [User Name], first_name [First Name], last_name [Last Name] 
    From tab_user
    ORDER  BY user_name

Select user_name [User Name], first_name [First Name], last_name [Last Name] 
    From tab_user
    ORDER  BY User Name
```

Above are the two queries,

1. Is there any difference because of the user_name used instead of User Name
2. Is there something that should be taken care/worried when using something like this.

Comment: Try imagining you're developing a parser. How will you parse the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query won't work. It needs to be this:

```
ORDER BY [User Name]
```

Once this is fixed there is no difference in the results. The syntax `SELECT User_Name [User Name]` creates an alias.

Answer (score 1):

the second query shouldn't work should it? you would need to

```
order by [User Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has to be user_name and not user uame. Space is not allowed.